# How to configure OpenSearch/ElasticSearch SQL plug-in as a datasource in Grafana?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, grafana, opensearch

OpenSearch (or ElasticSearch) has a [SQL plug-in](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html) that is accessible via `/_plugins/_sql` URL.

I can run a SQL Query on the ES Dashboard using a query like this:

```
POST /_plugins/_sql
{
  "query": "SELECT test_name,sum(run-time) FROM test_metrics GROUP BY test_name"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how can I add this SQL plug-in as a [datasource in Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/) so that I can run a similar query via Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Jan Garaj for the pointer, I was able to find a plugin that works for this purpose.

1. Install [grafana-infinity-datasource](https://github.com/yesoreyeram/grafana-infinity-datasource) plugin
2. Configure your authentication settings if applicable
3. Use these settings to configure your datasource

   - Type: `JSON`
   - Parser: `Backend`
   - Source: `URL`

     - URL: `<OPENSEARCH_SERVICE_IP>/_plugin/_sql`
4. Use these for your `URL Options`

   - HTTP Method: `POST`
   - Body Type: `Raw`

     - Body Content Type: `JSON`
     - Body Content:

       - e.g. `{ "query": "SELECT * FROM ES_DATA_INDEX_NAME }`
5. Configure your parsing options to map your data

   - Parsing options & Result fields: `datarows`
   - Columns: Map your fields (in order) to desired column-names

     - e.g. *Selector*: `0` *as*: `time`

Answer (score 2):

It is only POST request, so any plugin, which can make a POST request can do that: e.g. `marcusolsson-json-datasource`, `yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource`. Of course you will need to set proper header for authentication and suitable output format (json).